# Fibonacci summing and memoization

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I'm taking a programming course and there's a question about fibonacci sums and recursion.
the rules are as follows:

Write a function fibsum(N) that returns the sum of all even valued fibonacci terms that are less than N.

I've gotten close I think but my summation isn't working properly, also I'd like the function to work up pretty high (like N = 10**6 at least), here's my code so far

```
def fibsum(n, memo = {}):

added = 0

if n<0:
    return 0

if n== 1 or n == 0:
    return 1

else:
    if (n-1) in memo.keys():
        f1 = memo[n-1]
    else:
        memo[n-1] = fibsum(n-1)
        f1 = memo[n-1]

    if (n-2) in memo.keys():
        f2 = memo[n-2]
    else:
        memo[n-2] = fibsum(n-2)
        f2 = memo[n-2]

    if f1+f2 < 44:
        if (f1+f2) % 2 == 0:
            added += f1+f2
            print ("look here",added)
            return added 

    print (f1+f2)   
    return f1 + f2
```

I've left some print statements because I was trying to debug the problem but I've had no luck.

edit: I've been linked another question but it is done iteratively in that case, I would like to do it recursively if possible

Comment: This is a debugging problem, but I would advise splitting this problem in two: One a ‘fib()’ function which returns any value, and another which asks for even values and sums them.

Comment: the problem when I do that though is that if the function calls for n = 4*10**6 (like in a test case provided to us) it reaches the maximum recursion depth, I thought by terminating the function earlier it would make the function not go as deep in recursion. My problem is why the summation is not working with the added += section

Answer (score 1):

memoization wont help you with large values for fib

but as an aside seperate your logic

```
def fib(n):
    """
     simple recursive fibonacci function
    """
    if n == 0:
       return 1
    return n + fib(n-1)
```

then make a generic memoization decorator

```
def memoize(fn):
    cache = {}
    def _tokenize(*args,**kwargs):
        return str(args)+str(kwargs)
    def __inner(*args,**kwargs):
        token = _tokenize(*args,**kwargs)
        if token not in cache:
           cache[token] = fn(*args,**kwargs)
        return cache[token]
```

now just decorate your simple recursive function

```
@memoize
def fib(n):
    """
     simple recursive fibonacci function
    """
    if n == 0:
       return 1
    return n + fib(n-1)
```

now you can make your fibsum method (and also memoize it)

```
@memoize
def get_fib_nums(n):
    if n == 0:
       return [1]
    return [n] + get_fib_nums(n)



@memoize
def fibevensum(n):
    return sum(n for n in get_fib_nums(n) if n%2 == 0)
```

Comment: would this not still reach the maximum recursion depth if  something like n=4*10**6?

Comment: hence my opening statement that memoization will not save you for this ... even without the max recursion it would still take a very long time to calculate for large numbers... so i figured i would give you more general advise that will make your code easier to deal with